# Como "traduzir" SMARTY para JAVASCRIT ou mesmo JQUERY?

Tags: javascript, jquery, template

Eu tenho este código em um "template Smarty", (que roda em um server `Fuelphp`), simplesmente desejo "re-escrever" isso em **JavaScript** ou **Jquery**:

```
<select size="1" name="dw01">
  {section name=item start=1 loop=$item+1 step=1}
    {if $item_push}
      {foreach from=$item_push item=val}
        <option value="{$smarty.section.item.iteration}">
          {assign var="name" value="item_name`$smarty.section.item.iteration`"}
          {$val.$name|default:''}
        </option>
      {/foreach}
    {/if}
  {/section}
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Smarty é um motor de templating do PHP, ou seja, ajuda você a gerar HTML de forma rápida e dinâmica como no caso do seu exemplo, onde o Smarty está gerando um [`select form`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_form.asp) dinamicamente.

Para fazer a mesma coisa com JavaScript ou JQuery há diversas formas.

Puxando de um objeto, que pode ser um JSON gerado com PHP, usando só JavaScript:

```js
var options = '',
    //essa é a lista de onde sairão os valores das opções do select
    movie_list = {
      'The Revenant'       : 'The Revenant',
      'Deadpool'           : 'Deadpool',
      'Fight Club'         : 'Fight Club',
      "Birdman"            : 'Birdman',
      'Dallas Buyer\'s Club': 'Dallas Buyer\'s Club'
    };
//itera pela lista pra gerar as opções do select
for(var key in movie_list) {
    options += '<option value="' + key  + '">' + movie_list[key] + '</option>'
}
//inclui as opções no select de id movies
document.getElementById('movies').innerHTML = options;
```

```html
<select id="movies"></select>
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/L5dj72sw/7/)

Puxando de um objeto, que pode ser um JSON gerado com PHP, usando JQuery:

```js
var options = '',
    movie_list = {
      'The Revenant'       : 'The Revenant',
      'Deadpool'           : 'Deadpool',
      'Fight Club'         : 'Fight Club',
      "Birdman"            : 'Birdman',
      'Dallas Buyer\'s Club': 'Dallas Buyer\'s Club'
    };
   
for(var val in movie_list) {
    $('<option />', {value: val, text: movie_list[val]}).appendTo($('#movies'));
}
```

```html
<select id="movies"></select>
```

[**JSFIDDLE 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/LuaLa3n3/12/)

Existem muito mais possibilidades, depende muito do que você quer fazer e como quer fazer.

Comment: SENSACIONAL...  com os exemplos já em códigos  fica fácil da gente entender!   **vou poder estudar isso agora..**  Muito obrigado!

Comment: Sem problema! Boa sorte nos seus estudos!!!

Comment: Agora.. seguindo adiante..   tenho mais uma pergunta, por exemplo nessa pagina .. esse codigo SMARTY, trabalhando com um objeto ( com o nome de "$item_push"). mais abaixo na parte de < scripts >  estou colocando esse código java (que você deu como exemplo...)  porem com o objeto "$item_push"...  mas da erro...  LOgo a pergunta seria...  como usar o objeto "$item_push"  na parte de java? ou ainda .... como saber se eu posso usar esse mesmo objeto que estava no SMARTY,  la na parte de < scripts >  ? com JS ??

Comment: A resposta é: você não consegue! O JavaScript é usado para manipular o Document Object Model (DOM), criando, alterando o comportamento, passando novos atributos, modificando os existentes etc, atuando no front end (client side ou lado cliente).  O PHP (Smarty) atua junto com o HTML, mas atua no back end (server side ou llado servidor), então, você pode usar o Smarty para gerar uma lista e capturar essa lista com JavaScript para gerar o select.

Comment: Aqui alguns exemplos do fórum do Smarty: http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=87452&sid=bbb70837243b574dc88c07f38d9fed81

Comment: entendi!  e ja adaptei a minha necessidade!   valeu, inclusive pelos links extras!